Why does calculating $d\omega(V_1...V_k)$ explicitly in local coordinates not give the same formula as in the literature?
Let $\omega$ be a $k$-form, and $V_i$ vector fields.
To not have too many indices, let us suppose $k=1$ and we work in 3d. Now I cannot reconcile the following two ways of computing $d\omega(V,W)$.
First way: Calculate $d\omega$ in local coordinates (sum convention if the limits are trivial):
$$d\omega = d(\omega_i dx_i) = \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x^j} dx^j\wedge dx^i.$$ Now act on it with two vector fields, $V$ and $W$.
$$d\omega(V,W)=\frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x^j} (V_jW_i-V_iW_j) = V(\omega(W)) - W(\omega(V)).$$
Second way: Using the formula out of literature, I obtain:
$$d\omega(V,W)=V(\omega(W)) - W(\omega(V)) + \omega([V,W]).$$
Where does the third term come from? Do I misunderstand what $d\omega(V,W)$ is supposed to mean?

Why are you not differentiating the coefficients of $V$ and $W$ as well? If you choose $V$ and $W$ to be coordinate vector fields $\partial/\partial x^k$, then the Lie bracket terms disappear, as do the derivatives of the coefficients of $V$ and $W$.

Your first method’s last equal sign is wrong. You’re missing a product rule (in reverse). For example one term you have is  $(\partial_j\omega_i)V^jW^i$. But this is $V^j\partial_j(\omega_i W^i) - \omega_i(V^j\partial_jW^i)$. The first term gives $V(\omega(W))$ while the second is one part of the $\omega([V,W])$ term.

@peek-a-boo Thank you! I'm so stupid to have overlooked that, yeah.

@TedShifrin Thanks! I overlooked the fact that V(w(W)) acts also on W...

$\frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x_j} V_j W_i$ is not $V(\omega(W))$. The latter one has more terms. Try $\omega=f_1dx+f_2dy$, $V=g_1\partial_x+g_2\partial_y$ and $W=h_1\partial_x+h_2\partial_y$. Then,
$$
V(\omega(W))=V(f_1h_1+f_2h_2)\\
=g_1\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}h_1+g_1f_1\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x}
+g_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}h_2+g_1f_2\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x}\\
+g_2\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}h_1+g_2f_1\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x}
+g_2\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}h_2+g_2f_2\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x},
$$
$$
W(\omega(V))=W(f_1g_1+f_2g_2) 
\\= h_1\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}g_1+h_1f_1\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}+h_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}g_2+h_1f_2\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x}
\\+h_2\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}g_1+h_2f_1\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}+h_2\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}g_2+h_2f_2\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y},
$$
$$
[V,W]=g_1\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x}\partial_x+g_1\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x} \partial_y+g_2\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}\partial_x+g_1\frac{\partial h_w}{\partial y}\partial_y \\
-h_1\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}\partial_x-h_1\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x} \partial_y-h_2\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}\partial_x-h_1\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}\partial_y,
$$
$$
\omega([V,W])=f_1\left(g_1\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x}+g_2\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}-h_1\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}-h_2\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}\right)\\
+f_2\left(g_1\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x}+g_2\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial y}-h_1\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x}-h_2\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}\right).
$$
Thus if we compute $V(w(W))-W(w(V))-w([V,W])$, we obtain
$$
\left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \right)(g_1 h_2 - g_2 h_1).
$$
We know that $d\omega = \left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\right) dx\wedge dy$, and $dx\wedge dy(V,W)=g_1 h_2 - g_2 h_1$.
Your computation is right only when $V$ and $W$ are linear, $V=\sum_j a_j\partial_{x_j}$. If they are not linear, i.e. the coefficients are not constant, the derivation $V$ of $\omega(W)$ also affects on the coefficient of $W$, giving more terms.
